# Compare String with JSON String properties

Tags: java, json, string

I have a JSON String as-

```
[{"lv":[{"v":{"nt":"10;1341943000000","userId":622},"cn":0},
{"v":{"nt":"20;1234567890123","userId":622},"cn":0},
]
```

In this JSON String I will be having `userId` as the property for each values. It might be possible that in a Single JSON String I am having 10 userId property or 15 userId property. And `userId` will have some number always.

Each JSON String will have same number in `userId`. If you see the above JSON String, I have `622` as the number for each `userId`.

Now I am trying to compare `id` with `userId` in the JSON String. I am getting `id` value from some other means, like this-

```
final int id = generateRandomId(random);
```

So `id` value should be matching with all the `userId` property in a single JSON String.

And I am storing all the JSON String in `colData` `List<String>`. And currently I am trying to match `id` with `userId` using `contains` method of `String` class, which I believe is not correct because as soon as it finds one match then if conditions will get true (Which is wrong).

It might be possible that in a `Single JSON String` `20 userId properties` are there and `19 userId values` are matching with `id` but one `userId` property value is not same. So that use case will get failed in my below code. So how can I achieve this problem definition

```
for (String str : colData) {

   if (!str.contains(String.valueOf(id))) {

// log the exception here
handleException(ReadConstants.ID_MISMATCH, Read.flagTerminate);

   }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use Matcher

```
public class Uid {
    private static final Pattern USER_ID_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("userId\":\\d+");
    private static final String GENERATED_USER_ID = "userId\":622";
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> jsonData = new ArrayList<String>();
        jsonData.add("[{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"nt\":\"10;1341943000000\",\"userId\":621},\"cn\":0},{\"v\":{\"nt\":\"20;1234567890123\",\"userId\":622},\"cn\":0},]"); // this string contains multiple uids

        for (String s : jsonData) {
            Matcher matcher = USER_ID_PATTERN.matcher(s);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                String currentUid = matcher.group();
                 if (!currentUid.equals(GENERATED_USER_ID))
                    System.out.println("LOG exception, " + currentUid + " doesn't exists");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks sol4me for the suggestion. Are you sure, its working, bcoz it is not going inside the while loop in my case.

Comment: Did you adjusted GENERATED_USER_ID() according to your input? final int id = "userId" + generateRandomId(random);

Comment: Yeah I did that exactly as it is. But same result.